# I am facing this iisue while generating java classes from wsdl and xsd

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

I am facing this issue while generating java classes from wsdl and xsd.pls suggest.

1. Error message:  "Execution schema1-generate of **goal**
   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0:generate failed"
2. What has been tried ?  Eclipse installed jre set to jdk
3. Tried changing the jaxb plugin from org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 to
   org.codehaus.moj but still the same
4. I have multiple wsdls and
   they have xsds .   Below is my pom file configuration :

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<!-- <version>0.13.2</version> -->              
<executions>
<execution> 
    <id>schema1-generate</id> 
    <goals> 
        <goal>generate</goal> 
    </goals>  
    <configuration> 
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage> 
        <wsdl>true</wsdl> 
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate> 
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/wsdl</schemaDirectory> 
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>xyz.wsdl</include> 
        </schemaIncludes> 
        <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory> 
        <generatePackage>package_name</generatePackage> 
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir> 
    </configuration>             
</execution>
```

Comment: Hi..is your objective just to generate Java classes from wsdl and xsd or is there a constraint to do it only via a pom configuration?  You may check about wsimport cmd. Also, hope your Eclipse IDE is for Java EE Developers and not the Classic one. Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers comes with a menu option support for Generate->Jaxb Classes. You may try these alternatives. Good luck.

Comment: @PrithviRajMundur Thank you for your response. Yes I did try that, but yes, am trying to work it out through pom configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the below worked for me:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>0.13.2</version> -->
<execution>
      <id>AnyId-schemas</id>
      <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
       <configuration>
       <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
       <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
       <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
       <generatePackage>packageName</generatePackage>
       <schemaDirectory>src/main/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
       <schemaIncludes>
       <include>sourceOf the xsd</include>
       </schemaIncludes>
       </configuration>
  </execution>
```